# Netbeans platform - mark code?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

I want to write a java-plugin for Netbeans. Basically I want to mark code lines/segments so that I can reorganize code after it's written.

Example - If I write a code looking like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p1 = new Person();
    Person p2 = new Person();
    Person p3 = new Person();

    p1.printInfo();
    p2.printInfo();

    System.out.println(p3.getName());
}
```

I want to be able to mark code segments/lines, kinda like you would mark things in XML. So the marks would look something like this:

```
mark0: public static void main(String[] args) {
    mark1: Person p1 = new Person();
    mark1: Person p2 = new Person();
    mark2: Person p3 = new Person();

    mark1: p1.printInfo();
    mark3: p2.printInfo();

    mark3: System.out.println(p3.getName());
mark0:}
```

But at the same time, this is supposed to be a editor feature in Netbeans. So I don't want the marks to show up in the code. Therefore, I can't use straight forward XML.

But I haven't been able to find out what part of the Netbeans platform I need to learn to be able to code this. It would behave similar to a breakpoint, in that it highlights the code that's been marked and follows the line where ever it goes.

Is there a specific feature in the Netbeans platform that allows one to mark code like this? If not(and even if it is), is there a certain area I can learn more about in the Netbeans platform that you can name, that resembles this?

I'm not interested in using existing plugins for this, as I do this to learn and to customize my own plugin. However, if you think an existing plugin can help me find a solution then give it a shout out.

Comment: There is already a feature that does this. Use a single line comment like this: `// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Some code">` to mark the beginning and `// </editor-fold>` to mark the end.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a feature that hides those comments from the preview? If there are two single line comments for every line of code it quickly get's cluttered.

Comment: No I don't think that's possible. It's intended for larger blocks. If you want to mark a single line, why don't you use a bookmark? You then have a nice overview in the bookmarks window.

Comment: I'll check that out. If I can customize the bookmark feature, it'll be exactly what I was searching for. Thanks.